# Set tooltip display timer

Tags: winapi, timer, tooltip

I have been bothered by being unable to set a tooltip to display more than 33 seconds. My tooltip is created when I create a tab control with `TCS_TOOLTIPS`.

But one day, I found I can use the following code in the (subclassed) window procedure of my tooltip:

```
if (message == WM_TIMER && wParam == 4) {
    static int counter = 0;
    counter++;
    if (counter != 60)
        return 1;
    else
        counter = 0;
}

return CallWindowProc(DefWndProcTabTooltip, hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
```

Combine the code below:

```
    SendMessage(hwndTooltip, TTM_SETDELAYTIME, TTDT_AUTOPOP, MAKELPARAM((1000),(0)));
```

then the tooltip will be displayed for 60 seconds.

The condition `wParam == 4` means that the event of that WM_TIMER message is `The display timeout is achieved, and the tooltip is going to be hide`.

Although this is what I want to do, I got a question:

Is the test `wParam == 4` is the correct condition to test? What I mean is: the event id of the event `The display timeout is achieved...` is always 4? Is there a constant, say (...TOOLTIP)_TIMEOUTEXPIRE that one should (can) use.

Comment: You are asking about undocumented Windows internals.  Microsoft has no obligation to keep the timer ID the same in the next version of Windows.  Or the previous one, for that matter.  Code like this will arbitrarily fail to work some day.  You need to fix your UI problem instead.  If you display so much text that the user needs a minute to read it then it should never be a tooltip.